# JavaScript regex replace string characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to learn how to replace string?
I have an email address `someone@website.com` how do I replace `@` to `%` and `.` to `±`

Comment: type "javascript string replace" into your favorite search engine... Shows no effort/attempt or any research

Comment: Here you are. the reference of string.replace > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var replacements = {"@": "%", ".": "±"};
string.replace(/@|\./, function (match) {
    return replacements[match];
});
```

Comment: Didn't know about the callback option in `.replace()`, nice!